# How to display error on the client when using ASP.NET MVC AJAX

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC AJAX with the @AJAX.ActionLink helper to implement item deletion from a grid. When the request is executed it returns the grid without the deleted item and the AJAX helpers replace the grid. This works just fine but the problem is what to do if the item cannot be deleted (in my case due to foreign key constraints). How can I report the error to the client and display appropriate message. I don't want to use the OnFailure function blindly because I don't want to show the same error message for all errors. Ideally there will be a way to send specific error from the action and inspect the error in the JavaScript OnFailure function but I can't seem to find it.

Of course I can downgrade to returning JSON, manually executing AJAX calls and replacing UI elements but I don't really feel like it. I'd rather do something dirty like render a hidden input with the error information and check for it on the client but I don't want to do that either if there is better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return status code and error message from the controller and pass it to the ajax OnFailure function

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "The entity is currently used");
```

as shown here: [ASP.NET MVC AJAX onError handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771434/asp-net-mvc-ajax-onerror-handling/14778721#14778721)

and in the client side JS:

```
function deleteFailure(responce) {
    var statusCode = responce.status;
    var responceText = responce.statusText;
    if(statusCode == 409){
        //do something specific for specific errors
    }
    alert(responceText);
}
```